# Uploading images/files Android webview Kotlin

Tags: android, image, kotlin, file, webview

I have a button that will allow me to update photos to the backend. This is on web. I have an application that uses webview to show web app in mobile app. Now I want to upload images/files from mobile app in kotlin

I tried different github/ stack overflows. it didnt work.

Comment: and what did you try?